# Regex that matches strings only within a larger match

Tags: regex

I'm looking to create a single regex (for use in an Obsidian plugin) that will match certain lines under a specific Markdown header. Here's the source text:

```
# Inbox
​
- [ ] task 1
​
​
# Now
​
- [ ] task 2
- [ ] task 3
    - test bullet note
    - another bullet note
- [ ] task 4
​
# Next Actions
​
- [ ] task 5
```

I'd like the regex to capture all "tasks" under the header "# Now". Here, that would be task 2, task 3 (and its notes), and task 4.

I have the following regex which successfully captures tasks, but I don't know how to specify only tasks under that header.

```
^[ \t]*(-|\*|\d*\.) \[[xX ]\].*$
```

Comment: If supported, try it like this `(?<=^# Now\n(?:(?!\n# \w)[^])*)-[ \t]*\[[^][]*].*(?:\n[ \t]+-.*)*` https://regex101.com/r/zhG15D/1

Comment: Or using pcre like `(?:^# Now\R|\G(?!^))\R\K-\s*\[[^][]*].*(?:\R(?!#|\s*-\s*\[).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/feqkD6/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for your help.  I think the environment is EMCA Javascript for this, and neither of these match there, but I see that they do work in pcre.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to after process the regex matches with code?

Comment: nope, I'm trying to customize an existing plugin and I just get one regex for the match.

Comment: Will you know the number or range of numbers of each task? If so: `(?<=#\sNow\s\u200B\s)(- \[ \] task [2-4]\s)+|(- \[ \] task [2-4]\s)(?=\u200B\s)` or simply `(- \[ \] task [2-4]\s)+`

Comment: Referring to previous comment: use `\u` flag and `\u200B` for each zero width space. There's a zero width space before and after each `# Heading`.

Comment: @derekvan Is this a browser plugin? Using a lookbehind  `(?<=` has limited support  https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: @Thefourthbird after a bit more tinkering, I got the first regex you shared to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, you might use a lookbehind assertion for the `# Now` part, and then match the  `- [ ]` part followed by all lines that do not start with that pattern.

```
(?<=^# Now\n(?:(?!\n# \w)[^])*)-[ \t]*\[[^][]*].*(?:\n[ \t]+-.*)*
```

The pattern matches;

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind

  - `^# Now\n` Match literally at the start of the line
  - `(?:(?!\n# \w)[^])*` Match any char asserting not the `# \w` pattern directly to the right
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `-[ \t]*\[[^][]*]` Match - and optional spaces and then `[...]`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:\n[ \t]+-.*)*` Optionally repeat all lines that do not start with the `-[...]` pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zhG15D/1)